# using Schmitt trigger to debounce a switch

Tags: switches, schmitt-trigger, debounce

How can a Schmitt trigger be used to debounce a switch? please try to explain it with pictures as well.

Answer (score 4):

Since mechanical contacts are often very noisy on make and break, it is important to clean up the noise so it won't be counted as multiple button pushes.

This works because of the charge/discharge time constant of the capacitor and the large trigger hysteresis on the Schmitt trigger. The result being one single transition when a noisy input is used.

These circuits sacrifice a bit of timing accuracy (which is often irrelevant for a human interface) for a filtered, clean switch transition.

Simple debounce circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fE0jND.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>